# Asterisk Dialplan: How to detect when a call has been successfully answered?

Tags: asterisk, asteriskami, freepbx, dialplan

I'm having a really hard time figuring out if there is a trigger or a way to continue from the **Dial** action that allows you to detect if the call is answered. It seems like **Dial** doesn't respond until **hangup, busy, or congested**. What action or event am I missing that would tell me when the other end of the line actually answers the call? Hoping there is something like this available that I'm just missing:

```
exten => s,7,Dial(${ARG1},20,rt)       ; Ring the interface, 20 seconds maximum
exten => s,8,Goto(s-${DIALSTATUS},1)                    
; Jump based on status (NOANSWER,BUSY,CHANUNAVAIL,CONGESTION,ANSWER)
exten => s-ANSWER(do something)
```

Answer (score 3):

Finally figured it out. It involves calling the **M** flag in the **Dial** action call. By calling the **M** flag, you can call a custom macro that will execute immediately after the call is connected/answered.

Ex: **Dial(SIP/200,60,M(myCustomMacro))**

Hope this helps for any that were also curious.

Comment: I'm aiming to run a shell script  when a certain extension is called, and another script when the same extension finishes a call - would this be one way to go about it?

Comment: @Jb1128 Can you post your code inside extensions.conf. I faced the same problem. In addition what is ```myCustomMacro```?

Answer (score 1):

You can also do a Gosub when call is answered:

```
asterisk*cli> core show application Dial
...
    U(x[^arg[^...]]):
        x - Name of the subroutine to execute via Gosub
        arg - Arguments for the Gosub routine
Execute via Gosub the routine <x> for the *called* channel before connecting to
the calling channel. Arguments can be specified to the Gosub using '^' as a
delimiter. The Gosub routine can set the variable ${GOSUB_RESULT} to specify
the following actions after the Gosub returns
```